# How to show a particular div after click on a navigation link.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function showHyd() {
    window.location = "venueTravelHotel.html";
    $(".tab2").addClass("displayNone");
        $(".tab1").removeClass("displayNone");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class=" tab2">
    Tab2
</div>

<div class="tab1 displayNone">
    tab1
</div>
```

By default "tab1" div is displayNone and "tab2" is visible. When click on navigation link, I want go to that page and "tab1" div visible and "tab2" div hidden. But here after go to that page its loaded as default settings. How to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your CSS.  Most likely the problem lies there.

Comment: You'll need to have code on the other page that changes that.

Comment: once you navigate to the other page, the javascript on this page has no effect on the other page.

Comment: You're reloading the page. Can you post the html for the tabs?

Comment: Yes, that html has added.

Comment: If you need to navigate to a different page, you'll need to implement some server side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function showHyd() {
    window.location = "venueTravelHotel.html";
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $(".tab2").addClass("displayNone");
        $(".tab1").removeClass("displayNone");
    });
}
```

just try this.